# Перенос кода smtp в VSC++ 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Взял свой рабочий код написанный в консольном _gcc 2.95.2 для smtp и пробую перенести его в VC++ 2008 express edition (только начал её изучать):

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;  
#include &lt;iostream&gt;  
#include &lt;winsock.h&gt;  
#include &lt;Windows.h&gt;  
#include &lt;conio.h&gt;  

int main()  
{  
    WSADATA ws; 
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    hostent *d_addr;
    
    if (FAILED (WSAStartup (MAKEWORD( 1,1 ), &ws)))
    {
        printf("Error in WSAStartup(...): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (INVALID_SOCKET == (s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
    {
        printf("Error in socket(...): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    
    d_addr = gethostbyname ("smtp.yandex.ru");
    if (d_addr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in gethostbyname(...)\n");
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long *) d_addr->h_addr);
    addr.sin_port = htons (25);
    
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == (connect (s, (sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof (addr))))
    {
        printf("Error in connect(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    closesocket(s);
    
    WSACleanup();
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("Press any key\n");
    _getch();
}
```

После построения решения следующее:

```
------ Построение начато: проект: m, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
Компоновка...
m.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _connect@12 в функции _main
m.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _htons@4 в функции _main
m.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _closesocket@4 в функции _main
m.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _gethostbyname@4 в функции _main
m.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _WSACleanup@0 в функции _main
m.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _socket@12 в функции _main
m.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _WSAGetLastError@0 в функции _main
m.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _WSAStartup@8 в функции _main
D:\Create program\Visual C++\SMTP\m\Debug\m.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 неразрешенных внешних элементов
Журнал построения был сохранен в "file://d:\Create program\Visual C++\SMTP\m\m\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
m - ошибок 9, предупреждений 0
========== Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Скачивал студию с сайта microsoft, но после установки в ее папках не нашел winsock. Подгрузил winsock.h в папку Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include ничего не изменилось, но как сам понимаю связано это с отсутствием библиотеки winsock. Разъясните кто знает?

Comment: Точно, библиотеки нет.

Я делаю

     gcc ... -lws2_32 -lwsock32

а в программе

    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <ws2tcpip.h>
    #include <windows.h>

Answer (score 2):

Очень странно, что не обнаружили winsock. Очень странно. Может не то искали?

Есть [руководство](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) с минимальным примером.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// следующая строка очень важная - она заставляет линковщик добавить нужную либу
// в линуск системах она не нужна
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо KoVadim, скорее не там, нашел все это в папке SDK. Подключил в свойствах библиотеку Ws2_32.lib.
1. Построил решение успешно, отладочный exe запустил и он работал, но после попытки закрытия остался висеть и теперь даже через диспетчер завершить его не могу. 2 раза запускал код и каждый раз перезагружался.
2. Компилирую тоже успешно, но release не появляется.

Comment: очень странно. запускаете как? через студию или в консоли? Если через студию, то и завершайте через студию. Если в консоли - ctrl+C

Comment: 1. Через студию создаю debag, далее в папке запускаю exe, он откр в консоли, после нажатия в конце enter он завершается и закрывает консоль. Но в диспетчере процесс остается, и самое проблемное что после попытки убить процесс он остается и начинает тормозить компьютер.
2. Почему после успешной компиляции не появляется release, код ведь рабочий?
Построение начато: проект: m, Конфигурация: Debug Win32
Компиляция...
Пропуск... (изменения не обнаружены)
m.cpp
Журнал построения был сохранен в "..."
m - ошибок 0, предупреждений 0
Построение: успешно: 1, с ошибками: 0, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0